How do I tell which job caused a deploy pipeline to fail when they all pass in Azure DevOps
I have an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline with deploy jobs that is failing:

When I click the red X in the Stages column, it shows me the jobs that executed:

Every job I click shows no failures. Where in the Azure DevOps UI do I find the action that caused the pipeline to fail?
For reference, my pipeline YAML is as follows:
jobs:
- deployment: 
  environment:
    name: XXX-XXX-BLD
    resourceType: virtualMachine
  strategy:
    rolling:
      maxParallel: 5  #for percentages, mention as x%
      deploy:
        steps:
        - powershell: |
            # Use the Windows certificate store for Git's SSL certificates for both
            # agents (build and deploy).
            & C:\agents\build\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --global http.sslBackend schannel
            & C:\agents\deploy\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --global http.sslBackend schannel
        - powershell: | 
            #Requires -RunAsAdministrator 
            & choco upgrade buildstation --pre --no-progress


Hi @watkipet, can you please try to use the Timeline - Get REST API to get the detailed status of this run? I shared the PowerShell script in the answer.

Hi @watkipet, I'm curious if this happens all the time or if it can be reproduced every time? Can you please try to create a new run or just click the "rerun failed jobs" button to see if the same issue happens?

You can use the Timeline - Get REST API to get the detailed status of this run.
PowerShell script  sample:
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "projectname"
$buildId = ""
$PAT = ""

$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }
# Define the URL for the Timeline API
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/timeline/?api-version=7.1-preview.2"

# Make the API request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $Headers 

# Parse the response to get the records
$status = $response.records 

# Output
$status | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output ("Result : " + $_.result + ", State: " + $_.state  + ", Type: " + $_.type + ", Name : " + $_.name )
}

